# Move files within same GCP storage bucket and keep version history

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

How do you move files **within** the same storage bucket to different folders while keeping their version history? I couldn't find any related option for `gsutil mv/cp`.

Comment: You cannot move Cloud Storage objects. The process is to copy and delete. That process does not retain versions as you are only copying a version of an object.

Comment: @JohnHanley "You cannot move cloud storage objects" is wrong, see the `gsutil mv`[command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please post your comment as the answer. A few minor suggestions about Google Cloud Storage: Cloud Storage objects cannot be modified except for metadata and storage class. Cloud Storage Objects are **immutable**. Move operations are a copy and delete. The `gcloud mv` command is a combination of copy and delete.

Comment: My comment isn't the answer. I was trying to find a way to move files with their version history and still don't know how to do it with out of the box tooling. I would be really surprised if that cannot be done. It's a very basic feature/use case I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving objects (e.g., using `gsutil mv`) is accomplished using a copy followed by a delete, so the moved object is really a new object. There's no way to re-associate the version history of the old object to the new object.

`gsutil cp` [supports copying noncurrent versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-in-the-cloud-and-metadata-preservation) of files and since a move is just a copy followed by a delete, you could first copy with the metadata preservation option and then delete.

```
gsutil cp -A gs://bucket-name/oldDir/file gs://bucket-name/newDir/file
gsutil rm gs://bucket-name/oldDir/file
```

Comment: gsutil is simply a CLI that makes API calls for you.  The GCS service and its APIs do not support "moving" objects in the manner you're wanting.  An object is not a file; it does not have the same semantics as a traditional file, and it cannot be moved in the same way you can move a file on a filesystem.  An object exists at a given name (and version, if you have versioning enabled).  Its name cannot be changed; however, you can create a new object (with a different name) with the same contents and metadata, and delete the old one, which is similar to (but not 100% the same as) "moving" it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as a Community Wiki, so that it may help others too.

Using [`gsutil mv`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#description) command will allow you to perform a copy from source to destination followed by removing the source for each object.

Also as @John Henley stated in the comment and as per the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#gsutil).

> Note that while some tools in Cloud Storage make an object move or rename appear to be a unique operation, they are always a copy operation followed by a delete operation of the original object, because objects are immutable.

Comment: This wasn't my question. The point is about **keeping** the version history of a file. If a file has 11 versions they should exist after the move as well. I don't care whether the utility internally copies version by versions and adopting metadata or does it in some other way...